# Model vs event to communicate between directive for an angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, communication

I have an **angularjs** app with one ctrl and several **directives**.
To make directives reusable, there is no adherence with ctrl (isolate scope and mapping).

In this case, what is the best solution to allow communication between directive ?
Pros/Cons of using event ?
Pros/Cons of using only model and watch ?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to accomplish.
Do you want the directives to communicate with each other? do ypu have an common interest between your directives? which way you want to communicate? All off those situation have their own way(s) ti get solved.

Comment: A directive could contains the view (input) and the service to allow somebody to connect to a system.
An other directive could contains the view and service to show the cart customer.
So the second directive couldn't show any customer's data before
the first directive confirm the connexion.

Is that strategy is relevant ?
If yes, what is the best solution to allow communication between them ?

Comment: From my experience, directives are good to reuse markup/UI component. And for reusing other than UI, use services/factory. Typically the connexion should be managed by a service shared by both directives. In this way you don't have to wait if a directive is compiled or not... if the DOM is loaded or not. Other advise : keep it simple : do not do directive by default, use controllers and when something really needs to be reusable create directives...

Comment: So, you want to have a directive that is depended on antoher directives state. I'm not so sure that's a good idea, but I need to see some code to be sure. I wrote a plunk quite a while ago tthat might apply in your case, here is the link: http://plnkr.co/edit/qRZHcDGYCnMgfdLEiKoF?p=preview
Does that help a bit?

Comment: @asicfr, Is this question still open?

Comment: No, the different answers helped me to find a solution.